# read multiple table and write with chunk data to postgres database in pandas

Tags: pandas, loops

I have read multiple tables from postgres database and write it to anohter database through pandas as below but every time start from first row of chunk and write it to database.. i want to write complete first table then 2nd and so on ....
code:

```
chunksize=30
offset=0
j=0
print('now Connected 1st')
conn1=psql.connect()
conn2=dvd.connect()
print('now Connected 2nd')
table=['all_m_splty','all_m_lgd_states']
for i in table:
    sql="Select * from sha.%s Limit %d offset %d" % (i,chunksize,offset)
    print('now reading...')
    while True:
        for df in pd.read_sql_query(sql,conn1,chunksize=chunksize):
            print('now writting...')
            df.to_sql(name=i,con=conn2, if_exists='replace',index=False)
            offset+= chunksize
            j+=df.index[-1]+1
            print('Total no. of Rows inserted {} in {}'.format(j,i))
            while df.index[-1]+1 < chunksize:
                print('next')
                break
print("Main DisConnected!")
conn.close()
conn2.close()
```

**output**:

```
now Connected 1st
now Connected 2nd
hello! now reading start
now reading...
now writting...
Total no. of Rows inserted 30 in all_m_splty
now writting...
Total no. of Rows inserted 60 in all_m_splty
now writting...
Total no. of Rows inserted 90 in all_m_splty
now writting...
Total no. of Rows inserted 120 in all_m_splty
```

Comment: your code seems to be working, whats the issue here?

Comment: when i see data in table only first chunk data is write in table ..as first 30 rows only display in table..i kept two table in a list of table but it continue ....only first table not start 2nd table ..as only 55 rows in my first table.

Comment: That's because you're replacing the values in each call change `df.to_sql(name=i,con=conn2, if_exists='replace',index=False)` to `df.to_sql(name=i,con=conn2, if_exists='append',index=False)`

Comment: sir but it is well running with replace in single table ..